# Combining date and time (timestamp) in a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, unix-timestamp, valueerror

I wish to combine date and time into one timestamp on a list of dataframes and to designate a week to the call date.

Here is the error :
    ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp

I have used the following function :

```
def new_call_time(df):
    i=0
    df[' CALL_DATE_MANIPULATED']=str(df['CALL_DATE'][i]).split()[0] + ' ' + str(df['CALL_TIME'][i]) 
    df[' UNIX_TIME']= pd.Timestamp(df[' CALL_DATE_MANIPULATED'][i]).value//10 ** 9 
    df[' WEEK']=''

    for i in range(len(df)):
        df[' CALL_DATE_MANIPULATED'][i]=str(df['CALL_DATE'][i]).split()[0] + ' ' + str(df['CALL_TIME'][i])
        df[' UNIX_TIME'][i]= pd.Timestamp(df[' CALL_DATE_MANIPULATED'][i]).value// 10 ** 9
        df[' WEEK'][i]=df[' UNIX_TIME'][i]//604800

return df
```

Here is the function call statement :

```
for df in data_frame : 
    df = new_call_time(df)
```

Here are the tables I have read from excel sheets (contained in a list called data_frame) :

```
    CALL_DATE    CALL_TIME
    01-JAN-2016  00:15:06   
    01-JAN-2016  07:07:00

    CALL_DATE    CALL_TIME
    01-JAN-2016  08:40:38   
    01-JAN-2016  08:44:14   

    CALL_DATE    CALL_TIME
    01-JAN-2016  08:51:10   
    01-JAN-2016  09:06:31
```

This is working for an individual dataframe but isn't working for a list of dataframes.

The new tables should have the following columns too :
example : data_frame[0] -

```
     CALL_DATE       CALL_TIME  CALL_DATE_MANIPULATED UNIX_TIME  WEEK
     01-JAN-2016     00:15:06   01-JAN-2016 00:15:06  1451607306 2400   
     01-JAN-2016     07:07:00   01-JAN-2016 07:07:00  1451632020 2400
```

Thanks a lot :)))

Comment: Some problem with solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with indexing `str[0]` and then [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameters `errors='coerce'` for `NaT` if some values not matched format defined in `format` (parameter format is for better performance, but should be omitted):

```
def new_call_time(df):
    df['CALL_DATE_MANIPULATED'] = (df['CALL_DATE'].astype(str).str.split().str[0] + ' ' + 
                                   df['CALL_TIME'].astype(str))
    dates = pd.to_datetime(df['CALL_DATE_MANIPULATED'], 
                           errors='coerce', 
                           format='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    df['UNIX_TIME'] = dates.values.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9
    df['WEEK'] = df['UNIX_TIME'] //604800
    return df
```

Call function in list comprehension for new `list of DataFrames`:

```
data_frame1 = [new_call_time(df) for df in data_frame]
```

Comment: This works. It seems the parameter - errors = 'coerce' did the trick. Thanks once again for your help Jezrael:):)

Comment: I am getting a wrong result here. Consider the following output. The Unix time is showing negative. Any reason why? How can I correct it?

Comment: @SiddharthBachoti - I find problem. If there are not datetimes values get `NaT` because `errors='coerce'` parameter. Then `.values.astype(np.int64)` wronglyreturn bad negative number. Solution is replace these value to `NaT` by change `df['UNIX_TIME'] = dates.values.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9` to `df['UNIX_TIME'] = dates.mask(dates.notnull(), dates.values.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9)`

Comment: TypeError: cannot perform floordiv with this index type: DatetimeIndex

Comment: @SiddharthBachoti - How working alternative `df['UNIX_TIME'] = np.where(dates.isnull(), np.nan, dates.values.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9)` ?

Comment: Or maybe `df['UNIX_TIME'] = np.where(dates.isnull(), 0, dates.values.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9)` if want set `0` for missing values ?

Comment: @SiddharthBachoti - There is main problem missing values - if convert to NaN get floats column, if convert to `0` not sure if possible `0 unix time`

Comment: Just for your information:

CALL_DATE   CALL_TIME
2016-12-09     22:57:15
2016-12-09     20:58:55

With the previous solution you have provided, the above input gives answer as -9223372037 (Unix Time). However, CALL_DATE_MANIPULATED column is correct.

Comment: @SiddharthBachoti - thank you. So problem is if use `dates = pd.to_datetime(df['CALL_DATE_MANIPULATED'], 
                           errors='coerce', 
                           format='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')` then all data is necessary in same format `DD-MONTHNAME -YYYY  HH:MM:SS`. So if pass `2016-12-09 22:57:15` it return `NaT`, because different format. Solution is remove `format and errors parameters` - `dates = pd.to_datetime(df['CALL_DATE_MANIPULATED'])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184964/discussion-between-siddharth-bachoti-and-jezrael).